# How do I prevent blocked users from appearing in this list of users?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Django and programming noob here. I'm making an election information app, and on an election page I want to display all of the candidates that are running in the election, but I *do not* want to display the candidates which the moderators of the election have declared a blocked user.

I can display a list of all the candidates running in an election by using {% for candidate in election.candidate_set.all %}. However, I want to first check if the candidate is a blocked_user, and only display the candidate if they are not a blocked_user. As you can see in the template below, I thought that I could use the statement {% if candidate in election.blocked_users.all %}, but that does not work for me...

Sorry I'm such a noob. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**election_detail.html**

```
{% for candidate in election.candidate_set.all %}
    {% if candidate in election.blocked_users.all %}
        <!--do nothing-->
    {% else %}    
    <h3>{{ candidate.name }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Election(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    first_voting_day = models.DateField()
    last_voting_day = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    constituency = models.ForeignKey(Constituency)
    offices = models.ManyToManyField(Office)
    moderators = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='moderator')
    blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blocked_users', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('election_detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.id)})
```

**EDIT** - added the view for the election

**election.py**

```
class ElectionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Election
    context_object_name = "election"
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of filtering should be done in the controller instead. You filter the out the non-appropriate candidates in your Query before passing it to the template.

Comment: Thanks Lumpy Space Princess, I hadn't thought of that...I actually haven't done filtering like this from the controller before. 

I edited the view into the post above. I'm confused because blocked_users is a property of Election. What I want is for the blocked_users to not appear in the template election_detail.html when I call {% for candidate in election.candidate_set.all %}. Can I filter out blocked_users from election.candidate_set.all from the ElectionDetailView?  If I can, can you point me to the info I need to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This should select all candidates that don't have blocked_user relationships with election in your view.

```
eligible_candidates = election.candidate_set.exclude(id__in = election.blocked_users.all().values_list('id'))
```

then in your template

```
{% for candidate in eligible_candidates %}
<h3>{{ candidate.name }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Can be useful to move this filtering on to a method on the Model or Model manager if this filtering will be used often (DRY).